# Confused with a proof about paradoxical groups.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am reading about the [Banach-Tarski paradox](http://math.stmarys-ca.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Alex-Lowen.pdf), however, there are a couple of things about theorem 6 that confuse me. The image of theorem 6 and the proof can be found below. The first thing that confuses me are the braces marked by red in the image: $A_i^* = \{\bigcup_{g \in A_i} g(R)\}$. Are they really needed? If the braces are included then $A_i^*$ just becomes a set inside a set, which seems unnecessary. The second thing is the last sentence marked by red in the image. How does $X = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n g_i(A_i(R))$ follow directly from the fact that $G = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n g_i(A_i)$? Any help would be highly appreciated since I literally have no one to ask questions to.

> [image]

Comment: What's wrong with sets inside sets?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, there's nothing wrong with sets inside sets. In this case, it just seems unnecessary. If the braces are included then $A_i^* 
= \{ \{ \cdots \} \}$ which, I think, does not help to prove the theorem.

Comment: Also, `braces` (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket)

Comment: If everything makes sense ignoring the braces, then... feel free to ignore the braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ladies and gentlemen, I am happy to announce that we've had a breakthrough! I have finally understood this proof and I am here to share my thoughts. Let's first define $A_i(R)$ to be
$$A_i(R) := \bigcup_{g \in A_i}gR  \qquad  (1)$$
so $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n g_i(A_i(R))$ simplifies to $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n g_i(A_i^*)$, as mentioned in the picture in my post/question. We also know that the cosets of $R$ partition $X$, i.e $X = \bigcup_{g \in G}gR$. We also know that $G$ is a paradoxical group, so we can "choose" $g \in G$ in two different ways! To use this fact we will need to use the notation above (like we defined $A_i(R)$ in equation (1)). So $X = G(R)$. Now, since $G$ is paradoxical, we can substitute two different $G$'s in this equation and then simplify to see that $X$ indeed is $G$-paradoxical!

I have also concluded that the braces in red in the picture are a typo since (1) would not be equal to $A_i^*$.